Did the secret of Voldemort's seven Horcruxes become public after the seventh year?
After the final war in Hogwarts, Voldemort the Dark Lord was destroyed, forever. When curious people asked the heroes about their adventure, what would they say?  Did they describe the journey of finding and destroying the Horcruxes?
Did the Ministry of Magic cover all this up, people do not know that it is feasible to make more than one Horcrux?

Was it ever a secret? I only got the impression that it was not discussed in (one) magical school under one headmaster, and that it was both incredibly advanced and incredibly immoral, so most people did not know about it. But it was not a secret that anyone was actively working to suppress (Dumbledore just didn't want those books in the library). It as if you went to a random person and asked them what desomorphine was and how to make it: most people would have no idea, but it is hardly a secret

Are you asking if people generally knew about Horcruxes, or are you asking if it was  known that it was possible to make more than one?

@fez.  I was asking both. But since someone mentioned that the Horcrux is not top secret, I decided to modify my question to only ask the latter. If the story of Voldemort is unabashedly told, a very smart student would not need his/her Horace Slughorn to tell him/she that it is possible to make more than one Horcrux. Won't this be disturbing?

@Adamant "But it was not a secret that anyone was actively working to suppress (Dumbledore just didn't want those books in the library)." If Dumbledore removes those books from the library, even if he didn't do it himself, he is trying to stop people from reading about it.
That is the definition of suppressing knowledge.
